# Remover espaços em branco no Array

Tags: array, ionic, ionic3, ionic2, localstorage

Bem, estou desenvolvendo um app com o ionic 3. Quanto tento gravar alguns dados no vetor, aparece "\n" no inicio e no fim do array. Segue o código :

```
 element = this.pedido.produto;

if (this.vetCarrinhoAux.indexOf(element) === -1) {
  this.vetCarrinho.push(element);

  localStorage.setItem("vetor", JSON.stringify(this.vetCarrinho));
```

No LocalStorage, ele fica desse jeito :

```
[\n celular \n]
```

Comment: Tente utilizar o .trim()

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `.trim()`

```
element = this.pedido.produto;

if (this.vetCarrinhoAux.indexOf(element) === -1) {
  this.vetCarrinho.push(element);

  localStorage.setItem("vetor", JSON.stringify(this.vetCarrinho.trim()));
```